# GIMP: How to center a layer between two others

Tags: gimp, alignment

I want to center some text between two images.

The way I've been doing it is:

1. Take the left edge location of the right image.
2. Subtract the Right edge location of the left image.
3. Subtract half the length of the text. (Or any layer you wanted to center. You can find the size with the scale tool).
4. Left-Distribute the text with the Align tool and the number of pixels you calculated.

It seems like I should be able to do this much easier with the Distribute/Align tool, without needing a pencil and paper and basic math.

One of the related questions: "GIMP: find midpoint / arbitrary division between two points" seems to say this is the only solution.

Comment: Hey itsnotmyfault, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My approach would be as follows:

Assuming that your two images are layers, and that the text layer does exist already:

1. create a selection that spans the area between the two layers' right and left edges
2. use the Align tool on the text layer, choose "Selection" in the "Relative to" dropdown in its tool options
3. Align as desired with the buttons in the Align tool options

If this does not solve your task, then you should add an image to your question and point out where it differs from your intended result.

Answer (score 2):

I’ve used the following method to center one or more layers between any two points:

1. Create your new text (or whatever) layer(s) between the two points (put it off-center a little so that you will see it move when you finally center it).
2. Add a new transparent layer over your entire graphic (and make sure it is the active layer).  Call it *guide layer* or something like that.
3. Using the pencil tool, draw a perfectly horizontal line between the two points (click starting point, hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, scroll right, click end point, release mouse, release keys).  Make the line somewhat thick so you can work with it.
4. Use Autocrop Layer to “shrink” the new layer down to the line only.  Use the *Move* tool to adjust the position of the line if you need to.
5. Select the *Alignment* tool, then select the line created in step 3 and every other layer that you want to center to it. The guide layer should still be the active layer.
6. Display the *Tools Options* dialog (if not already displayed) and select *Relative to: Active layer*, then click *Align center of target*.

Now all of your layers are centered to the guide line and you can delete the guide layer.